# Почему не рендерится activeTextInput

Tags: php, yii2

Создаю свой виджет с кастомным поведением через JavaScript

Вот код виджета:

```
<?php

namespace backend\components\widgets\characterDelimiter;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\InputWidget;

class CharacterDelimiterWidget extends InputWidget {

    public $lenght,
           $needToDelimiterStr,
            $delimeterCssClass,
            $delimeterCssStyle,
            $name,
            //переменные для activeForm
            $options = [],
            $settings = [],
            $model,
            $value,
            $selector,
            $attribute;

    public function init() {

        $this->options = [
            'class' => $this->delimeterCssClass, 
            'style' => $this->delimeterCssStyle, 
            'id' => $this->name . '_' . $this->attribute . '_id', 
            'maxlength' => $this->lenght, 
            'name' => $this->attribute];

        $specialClass = '<div class="clearfix super-special-class"></div>';

        if (parent::hasModel()) {

            echo $specialClass, Html::activeTextInput(
                    $this->model, 
                    $this->attribute, 
                    $this->options);

        } else {

            echo $specialClass, Html::textInput(
                    $this->name, 
                    $this->value, 
                    $this->options);
        }
        parent::init();
    }

    public function run() {
        $view = $this->view;

        $view->registerJs(
                <<< JS
                var left = $this->lenght; //кол-во разрешенных символов
                console.log();
                $("#counter_$this->attribute").text("Символов осталось: " + left);
                if ($this->needToDelimiterStr) {
                    $("#$this->attribute").keyup(function() {
                        left = $this->lenght - $(this).val().length;
                        if (left < 0) {
                            left = 0;
                        }
                        $("#counter_$this->attribute").text("Символов осталось: " + left);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#counter_$this->attribute").text("Неограниченный ввод");
                }
JS
                , yii\web\View::POS_LOAD);
        return;
    }
}
```

Если я вызываю его в представлении вот так:

```
 <?php
 echo CharacterDelimiterWidget::widget(['lenght' => 10,
    'name' => 'example',
    'needToDelimiterStr' => 'true',
    'delimeterCssClass' => 'text-center',
    'delimeterCssStyle' => 'margin: 0 auto']);
```

То, рендерится вот такой input

```js
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  var left = 10; //кол-во разрешенных символов
  console.log();
  $("#counter_").text("Символов осталось: " + left);
  if (true) {
    $("#").keyup(function() {
      left = 10 - $(this).val().length;
      if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
      }
      $("#counter_").text("Символов осталось: " + left);
    });
  } else {
    $("#counter_").text("Неограниченный ввод");
  }
});
```

```css
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="asdasd__id" class="text-center" name="asdasd" maxlength="10" style="margin: 0 auto">
```

А если вот так:

```
<?php
$model = ThisDay::findThisDayNews(614932);
foreach ($model as $key => $value) {

        $form->field($model, "news_name")->widget(backend\components\widgets\
                characterDelimiter\CharacterDelimiterWidget::className(), [
            'lenght' => 10,
            'needToDelimiterStr' => 'true',
            'delimeterCssClass' => 'text-center',
            'delimeterCssStyle' => 'margin: 0 auto'
        ]);
}
```

То не рендерится ничего кроме js'a. При этом `parent::hasModel()` возвращает `true`, а

```
var_dump($specialClass, Html::activeTextInput(
                $this->model, $this->attribute, $this->options));
```

возвращает вот такой инпут:

```css
.text-center {
  text-aling: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="_news_name_id" class="text-center" name="news_name" value="Тестовое значение полученное из базы данных" maxlength="10" style="margin: 0 auto">
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Я забыл про `echo` >,<

```
echo $form->field($model, "news_name")->widget(backend\components\widgets\
                    characterDelimiter\CharacterDelimiterWidget::className(), [
                'lenght' => 10,
                'needToDelimiterStr' => 'true',
                'delimeterCssClass' => 'text-center',
                'delimeterCssStyle' => 'margin: 0 auto'
            ]);
```